# Adding swig as template engine to keystoneJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine, swig-template, keystonejs

I have added swig as the template engine to my KeystoneJS project but it will not load my templates. I have added the following to my keystone.js file:

```
// Require keystone
var keystone = require('keystone');
var swig = require('swig');

// Initialise Keystone with your project's configuration.
// See http://keystonejs.com/guide/config for available options
// and documentation.

keystone.init({

    'name': 'it_blog',
    'brand': 'it_blog',

    'less': 'public',
    'static': 'public',
    'favicon': 'public/favicon.ico',
    'views': 'templates/views',
    'view engine': 'swig',
    'custom engine': swig.renderFile,
    'auto update': true,
    'session': true,
    'auth': true,
    'user model': 'User',
    'cookie secret': '*omitted*'

});
```

Here is the node.js error that I get:

```
Error thrown for request: /
Error: Failed to lookup view "index"
  at Function.app.render    (/Users/admin/Desktop/Development/my_project/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:495:17)
```

I followed the steps listed here: https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone/issues/270

Comment: Express does some crazy things with file extensions. Is it automatically trying to find `index.swig`, but your file is `index.html`?

Comment: @PaulArmstrong no luck using .swig files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [Keystone Generator](https://github.com/JedWatson/generator-keystone/) for Yeoman now includes Swig support and example templates, I recommend using that to start a project, selecting `swig` as the template engine, and copying its implementation.

Instructions for getting started with the generator are here: http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Jed. This was a great addition to the already wonderful KeystoneJS package.